# How do I include an Angular component that contains other non HTML elements like mat-icon via CDK Overlay

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-ivy

I am attempting to implement a Speech To Text feature within my App by using a directive [appSpeechToText] which I can apply to any input/textarea field, the component basically displays a Record, Pause and Stop buttons for which I wish to use the `<mat-icon>` element.

My directive works in that if I create the HTML

```
<p>BANG!</p>
```

Everything compiles as you would expect and the label BANG! is displayed next to my textarea control as I would expect, however when I change the HTML to

```
<mat-icon>not_started</mat-icon>
```

I get the following message during compilation: -

```
src/app/shared/components/speech-to-text/speech-to-text.component.html:2:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2     <mat-icon>not_started</mat-icon>
      ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/shared/components/speech-to-text/speech-to-text.component.ts:5:18
    5     templateUrl: './speech-to-text.component.html',
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SpeechToTextComponent.
```

I am at a loss as to how I inform Angular that I wish to use the MatIconModule?

**To clarify**

The component is launched via a directive using

```
this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(SpeechToTextComponent))
```

I am not referencing the component in any module because it is dynamically attached to the overlay. I do however have the `MatIconModule` imported in my `app.module.ts` file but to no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add the `MatIconModule` to the `imports` in your `app.module.ts` or (if existing) `speech-to-text.module.ts`.

Comment: thank you, I have included the MatIconModule in my app.module.ts file, I have added some clarification to my original question.

Comment: My first guess would be, that the component is not attached to the the app.module, therefore requiring an own module like `speech-to-text.module.ts` and importing the Mat module there

Answer (score 0):

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
```

Comment: thank you, I have included the MatIconModule in my app.module.ts file, I have added some clarification to my original question.

Comment: import MatIconModule in speech-to-text.component.ts file

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably missing a module import in your app module .ts file.

If you are just getting started with Angular Material components, make sure to refer to the getting started guide:
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started
And the icon component reference:
https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api

Comment: thank you, I have included the MatIconModule in my app.module.ts file, I have added some clarification to my original question.

Comment: then probably your component belongs to a different module, and that module should be importing the MatIconModule.

Comment: As Marek W suggested, a speech-to-text.module.ts or something like that

Comment: Maybe try this https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules @AndrewHB

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it I needed to add the `SpeechToTextComponent` into the `declarations` array within my `app.module.ts` file, having said that because of the need to reference both the directive and the component it would probably make sense to put it into it's own module as mentioned above.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { SpeechToTextComponent } from '../components/speech-to-text/speech-to-text.component';
import { SpeechToTextDirective } from '../directives/speech-to-text.directive';

@NgModule({
    imports: [MatIconModule],
    declarations: [SpeechToTextComponent, SpeechToTextDirective],
    exports: [SpeechToTextDirective]
})
export class SpeechToTextModule {}
```